# Why does my class raise an AttributeError?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I might be blind, but I really can't see why this class fails with:

> AttributeError: NextSunday instance has no attribute 'trigger'

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
from datetime import timedelta


class NextSunday():
    def __init__(self, trigger=None):
        """
        Get date of, and number of days until, next Sunday.

        Arguments:
        - `trigger`: Add an extra week if less than trigger number of days.
        """
        self.str = u'%s (%s days)' % (self.date().date(), self.no_days())
        self.trigger = trigger

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.str

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Next Sunday: ' + self.str + '>'

    def no_days(self):
        """Get date of next sunday. """
        days = None
        for i in range(7):
            dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=i)
            if dt.weekday() == 6:
                days = i

        # Add another week if there are less days left then trigger
        if self.trigger:
            if days < self.trigger:
                days += 7

        return days

    def date(self):
        # The datetime obj contains the next sunday, but also the current time
        dt_of_next_sun = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=self.no_days())

        # Get the whole day
        date_of_next_sun = datetime.combine(dt_of_next_sun.date(),
                                            time(23, 59))

        return date_of_next_sun
```

Comment: eliminiate the unnecessary lines, till you locate the root of the problem.

Comment: The full stacktrace would identify the originating line.

Comment: This is why I developed the habit of always setting instance variables first, at the top of the initializer, before calling any methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch these

```
    self.str = u'%s (%s days)' % (self.date().date(), self.no_days())
    self.trigger = trigger
```

like this

```
    self.trigger = trigger
    self.str = u'%s (%s days)' % (self.date().date(), self.no_days())
```

because otherwise the `no_days` method is called *before* the `self.trigger` attribute is created. This is bad because the `no_days` method tries to read the value of the `self.trigger` attribute:

```
if self.trigger:
    if days < self.trigger:
```

Comment: Oh, that was interesting. It solved the problem (marks the question as solved soon). But why is this? I can't see it.

Comment: you call `no_days` before `trigger` is set.

Comment: @Niclas I've updated my answer with what is hopefully a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @lazyr Oh, that should be obvious. But I havn't encountered this before so I did'nt think about it. Thanks alot!